# Is loot quality affected by location?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds there are several different areas that a player can head to to find various different weapons, attachments and items. Each time a new game starts new items are randomly generated throughout the map. So just because you found a certain weapon in a specific house last game, is no guarantee you will find that same weapon in the same spot the next game.

However in the game it is commonly accepted that certain area's, such as the Military Base Island, the School, or Hospital are more likely to have higher quality loot or weapons (More sniper rifles, higher level backpacks/armour ect.). I have yet to be able to find anything that supports the idea that the higher level of gear is *a result* of the area vs. those areas just have a *higher number of spots* where loot spawns. For example are you more likely to find higher quality gear in a roadside shed on Military Island than in the same type of shed on the main Island, or is their no difference?

The main question is, **is the quality of the weapons, attachments, and gear you find affected by the area that you find it in?**

Hopefully there would be some information on loot spawning from the developers, but any information gathered by testing or data-mining would be appropriate as well.

Comment: It's the same thing... You tend to find better quality loot in those areas too... Air drops obviously drop the best stuff as well... I'm not sure this warrants a question

Comment: @n_palum Not necessarily, if loot quality is the same regardless of location then you could reasonably assume that you would find the same stuff in one of the apartment blocks, as you would on the military island (similar if slightly less loot density). But the apartment blocks are a lot safer as there may be less players and you don't have to cross those godforsaken bridges and deal with bridge trolls.

Comment: I didn't say it was the same regardless of location. The question on loot spawn rates is associated with quality too.

Comment: @n_palum I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say? Could you clarify?

Comment: The map that shows higher loot spawns, also depicts quality. At the military base, there is higher amount and higher quality loot.

Comment: @n_palum Oh, I guess you are talking about the [ShatterNL Map](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=898402255)? It is a nice map but their isn't really any sources for where he got the data from...

Comment: It's been checked over and confirmed more or less by a lot of players. It's mostly a consensus at this point, and from playing you can see it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the quality of the weapons, attachments, and gear you find affected by the area that you find it in?

Yes. But there is no real information available about how the loot spawn system works. As the spawning is made by the server so there will be no data mining data.

But by experience it is quite obvious. Especially in squad games you will be able often able to loot areas without competition (in squad games the players are not that much scattered all around the map). [ShatterNL map](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=898402255) is quite good but not percent. For example in Yasnaya Polyana the loot on the east (hospital and police station) is significant better than the loot in the north-west part of Yasnaya Polyana